# Android Studio JNI open sqlite3 database for write failed: access denied

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk

I'm making an Android app which needs to maintain a database from the native code in c++. I'm using sqlite3 by including sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h in my project. I saw online this should be enough but I also included sqlite3ndk.c/.h, and before trying to open the database I have to call `sqlite_ndk_init(AssetManager am)`. (or it will give a "could not open database file" error, please let me know if this is not the expected behavior.)

I can open the database as `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` with no problem, but when opened as `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` it gave an "access denied" error. The database file I want to open was given full rwx permission to all users. How can I give the app the permission to write to the database? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the database file store? If it's external storage you probably need permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: @wierzmar The database file is in the assets folder and I have requested write permission in the manifest already :(

Comment: I don't think you can write something to asset dir. You could place the database file to internal storage instead: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: @wierzmar That solved the problem! Thanks a lot!